# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'street1' of undefined at TenantsDetailsComponent_Template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I am facing this error while component load T

> typeError: Cannot read property 'street1' of undefined
> at TenantsDetailsComponent_Template (tenants-details.component.html:92)

**component.ts**

i defined my object here

`tenantDataFromListComp : TenantInfoResponse = { };`

**TenantInfoResponse interface** has the property of type Address interface like

```
import { Address } from './address';
import { CommunicationSettings } from './communicationSettings';
import { ContactData } from './contactData';
import { CurrencyPreferenceEntry } from './currencyPreferenceEntry';
import { DmsSettings } from './dmsSettings';
import { DocumentStatus } from './documentStatus';
import { RepairOrderSettings } from './repairOrderSettings';


export interface TenantInfoResponse { 
address?: Address;
communicationSettings?: CommunicationSettings;
contactData?: ContactData;
currencyPreferences?: Array<CurrencyPreferenceEntry>;
defaultLocale?: string;
defaultTimezone?: string;
director?: string;
displayName?: string;
dmsSettings?: DmsSettings;
emailOnStatusChangedList?: Array<DocumentStatus>;
forwardEmailAddress?: string;
fullName?: string;
legalEntityName?: string;
paymentLinkValidity?: number;
recipientDataLearning?: boolean;
registeredSeat?: string;
registration?: string;
reminderInterval?: number;
repairOrderSettings?: RepairOrderSettings;
returnEmailAddress?: string;
style?: TenantInfoResponse.StyleEnum;
surveyScript?: string;
tenantCode?: string;
tenantCodeExternal?: string;
vatCode?: string;
  }
```

And **Address interface** is like

```
export interface Address { 
city?: string;
country?: Address.CountryEnum;
postcode?: string;
province?: string;
street1?: string;
street2?: string;
}
```

**component.html**

```
   <div class="card shadow p-0 mb-2 bg-white rounded">
                    <div class="card-header  text-white bg-dark"> Tenant Address</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="street1">Street 1</label>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                        id="street1" name="street1" [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.address.street1" >
            
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label>Street 2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                        name="Street2" [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.address.street2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label>Post Code</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PostCode"
                                    [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.address.postcode">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label>City</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city"
                                    [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.address.city">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label>Province</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="province"
                                    [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.address.province">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label>Country</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country"
                                    [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.address.country">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          

                    
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

Comment: This is not my area of expertise but I suggest you add a bit of context to the question to explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

there is a better way to check if that property exists on your object or not

```
   <div class="card shadow p-0 mb-2 bg-white rounded">
                    <div class="card-header  text-white bg-dark"> Tenant Address</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="street1">Street 1</label>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                                        id="street1" name="street1" 
 add '?'for the properties which might be empty---> [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp?.address.street1" > 
            
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label>Street 2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                        name="Street2" [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.?address.street2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label>Post Code</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PostCode"
                                    [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.?address.postcode">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label>City</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city"
                                    [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.?address.city">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label>Province</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="province"
                                    [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.?address.province">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label>Country</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country"
                                    [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.?address.country">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          

                    
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

This can be a simple way of avoiding such errors in HTML template. However, you can add *ngIf to check whether the values exist or not, but that becomes more complex if you have more fields to validate.

Comment: I tried this but it gives `Parser Error: Unexpected token ?, expected identifier or keyword at column 24 in [tenantDataFromListComp.?address.street1]`

Comment: My bad, use [tenantDataFromListComp?.address.street1]. like this -- it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

### Simple method:

It happens because when your HTML file renders, your `tenantDataFromListComp` variable is `{}` and it's obvious that `{}` has no `address` and `street1`.
There are many methods that can solve this problem. One of them that I always use is adding `ngIf` to the parent element or itself. In your case it is something like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" *ngIf="tenantDataFromListComp.address && tenantDataFromListComp.address.street1">
    <label for="street1">Street 1</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="street1" name="street1" [(ngModel)]="tenantDataFromListComp.address.street1" >
</div>
```

### Better method:

Stop rendering till your requests from the backend responded.
You can use promises with async/await

```
await this.http.post(...).toPromise(value => {
  ...
});
```

You should get data in `ngOnInit` or something like this.
For more information you can checkout:

- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
- [ES8 async/await](https://medium.com/@_bengarrison/javascript-es8-introducing-async-await-functions-7a471ec7de8a)
- [async/await tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9)
- [async/await explained](https://tutorialzine.com/2017/07/javascript-async-await-explained)

Comment: tenantDataFromListComp has type TenantInfoResponse  `tenantDataFromListComp : TenantInfoResponse` and TenantInfoResponse has defined address property type `export interface Address { 
    city?: string;
    country?: Address.CountryEnum;
    postcode?: string;
    province?: string;
    street1?: string;
    street2?: string;
}`

Comment: your's solution is working but problem is that i want each element on component load. With your solution it condition is not true then element will not render until i update the values. Furthermore, i have so many other fields like, contact information have different fields i cant write *ngIf to each elment

Comment: I will update my answer for I know what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can define the new Object to contain an address with an empty address object

```typescript
 tenantDataFromListComp : TenantInfoResponse = { address: {} };
```

The error is being thrown because `tenantDataFromListComp.address` is undefined in `{}`

Comment: Before i was using the same technique but one of my friend told me that this is not the right way as in ` TenantInfoResponse` interface every thing is defined. Furthermore, i am confused there are some properties which have string, numbers or Boolean data type can be accessible using the same  `tenantDataFromListComp.displayName`. I update the question to show you my complete ` TenantInfoResponse` interface